# How to find the tangent line of arctany=arcsinx

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

I am really confused on how to find the derivative/tangent line of arctan(y) = arcsin(x) when x = sin(1).

I subbed x in and got arctan(y) = 1 but I am unsure where to go from here.

Answer (score 0):

If $y(x)=\tan(\arcsin x)$, then $y'(x)~=~?$